# Calculate how long an activity is in Foreground

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-activity

My app contains 3 different activities: HomeActivity, VideoActivity, ImageActivity, etc.

Home page contains several buttons to launch videos and images.

I need to record metrics on how long an activity is in foreground. For example, say user opens a video, plays for 10 seconds, goes back to Home page, opens image for 5 seconds, goes to home page, opens another image 10 seconds.

I want to record something like

```
<ActivityName, ElapsedTime>
VideoActivity: 10s
HomePage: 1s
ImageActivity: 5s
HomePage: 2s
ImageActivity: 10s
```

I don't have to store ActivityName and ElapsedTime in sharedPreferences or anything. I'm using an internal api to send the data to backend as soon as ElapsedTime is calculated.

This is what I currently have:

```
public class HomeActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {
    @Inject
    lateinit val someBackend: SomeBackend
    
    var startTime: Long = 0L

    override fun onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
    }
    
    // When activity comes into foreground
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    }

    //when activity loses focus
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        someBackend.record("HomeActivity", elapsedTime)
    
    }
}
```

```
public class VideoActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {
    @Inject
    lateinit val someBackend: SomeBackend
    
    var startTime: Long = 0L

    override fun onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
    }
    
    // When activity comes into foreground
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    }

    //when activity loses focus
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        someBackend.record("VideoActivity", elapsedTime)
    
    }
}
```

```
public class ImageActivity : AppCompatActivity()  {
    @Inject
    lateinit val someBackend: SomeBackend
    
    var startTime: Long = 0L

    override fun onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ....
    }
    
    // When activity comes into foreground
    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        startTime = System.currentTimeMillis(); 
    }

    //when activity loses focus
    override fun onPause() {
        super.onPause()
        elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime
        someBackend.record("ImageActivity", elapsedTime)
    
    }
}
```

This implementation looks so simple I'm worried that I'm probably missing something here...
Are there any cases that this doesn't account for?
Is there a better approach than this?

(If this is relevant) This is for a demo app that runs on devices. So HomeActivity will be running all the time unless user interrupts.
Home activity can be running for 2 days or 2 months....

Comment: That's pretty much what you want.  It is that simple to calculate.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks` and use `registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks` in the application class. this helps you to track activity states and calculate actives tims